# SSMA for Access -- No Objects Were Selected

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-migration-assi

Is there a version of this app that actually **works**??? I'm running version 9.1 and it's terrible.  Sometimes it will migrate a table but not the data, and 90% of the time it will say "*No objects were selected*" even though all the tables have check-marks.  I can get it to work every so often, and then it just breaks completely.

I am so close to migrating my database from ACCESS 2013 to SSMS 18... if only I could get SSMAfA to work consistantly.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a baby sitting service.

That tool been around for more then 10+ years. We don't see nor have daily posts here on this rather active SO form in regards to Access. Maybe computers are not just your thing?

Your screen shot shows the selected tables, but does not seem to show the (1/1) for that database.

Like this:

[image]

And your 2nd screen shot?

That suggests you not connected corrected to the target sql server database.

As I stated, the tool is not really hard to use, and in IMHO has only one real "gaff". and that issue was already noted to you. (that you have to click on the database in the left tree before the buttons are enabled such as "convert schema" and "migrate data").

And what does the lower left show for the sql server side?

(hit re-connect to sql server so we at least know we have a live connection).
(it should not show off-line)

THEN navigate down the tree to dbo for that database, what do you have?

I see this, but not the tables (I removed them for this post)

[image]

So no tables? I SHOULD be able to expand the tables in above, but no tables?

Then right click, and sync

[image]

Now I SHOULD not have to do the above - maybe we messed up. But, after I do the sync, I now see the tables on sql server.

eg this:

[image]

So, do you see your tables now under the dbo tree ???

If yes, then now try this:

back on top left, make sure you click on (highlight) the database, like this:

[image]

Now, if you do NOT see the tables after that right click and sync? Then use convert, load and migrate from the menu.

but, those tables should appear in the dbo tree part lower left. If they do, then you can migrate the data over and over as you wish. (and it will overwrite the data on sql server).

Some more things to try.

Try removing the access database from the project, and then re-add it.

So this: (we now upper left)

[image]

Now, save, and then re-add the access database again. See if that helps.

But, before you hit migrate button, do drill down into dbo on the lower left - make sure the tables exist, and are selected.

This is not a hard tool to use, but it does have a "way" it works. I have spent up to 3 days JUST in the tool BEFORE I migrate. In other words, it does have a lot of options, but once you  done all that work, then you can re-migrate a again, and that is perhaps the BEST feature of SSMAA.

My only other beef? I find SSMAA is not all that stable - and it has shut down on me more often then I like.

Last but not least?
If you need a LOT more hand holding then what this forum SO can offer?

consider the Access form "Utter Access". All of the industry stall warts, access experts not only hang out on UA, but they also are able in most cases to offer a lot more hand holding. It really is a great Access centric forum, and you might consider asking your questions in that forum.

It can be found here:

https://www.utteraccess.com/

Also, since you noted you ARE using Access 2007, then have you attempted to use the migration system built into Access 2007? is is a LOT easier to use, but then of course lacks MANY options that SSMAA offers. But, it not clear why you not attempted to try the access built in migration system - yet are looking for a different tool to try? Why?
Now, you might have a VERY good reason to not try this alterative I have suggested to you, but you NOT GIVEN  a reason why as such.

If SSMAA not working for you, or is above your pay grade, then try the Access one. As I stated, it can be found in Access versions up to 2010, but versions after that don't have a built in migration system to SQL server, and thus SSMAA is the tool of choice.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so much.  If I said I was using ACCESS 2007, I was mistaken.  I'm using 2013, so the  migration system built into Access is not available.  I'll check out your suggestions and hope that they help.  Thanks.

Comment: All I'm saying is this should not be such a hassle. Yes, you had suggested you were using a2007, and further suggested you can't upgrade anything. Again, no big deal. As noted, consider the UA forum I suggested, as it also great for further questions you no doubt will have after you migrate - and the types of questions, and even recommendations of software are permitted on that site (and not here on SO).

Comment: UA looks like a great forum.  I already found this question: https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/2061146?post=unread# (one of the contributors seems VERY familiar!).  Using a Make-Table got me a little further down the line.  I'll be posting my questions on UA but wanted to let you know how valuable your time has been.